# How can I override the * selector for CSS to change my body's background colour?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use a container `div` to house my webpage, and make its background white. However, behind that container I want to make the background black. How can I do this? When I use *, it makes the entire page black, which I do not want.

```
<html>
<body>
<p>Hello World</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: welcome please share your html

Comment: Hi there! Would you mind showing us what your HTML looks like?

Answer (score 0):

To set the background of your entire body simply add the following to your css

```
html {
    background-color: black;
}

body {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Checkout https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors for more information about different kinds CSS selectors and how to use them.

> The CSS type selector matches elements by node name. In other words, it selects all elements of the given type within a document.
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> element { style properties }
> ```

Comment: I'm trying to set the background of the body white, but the background behind that (the body isn't 100% width), black.

Comment: @fwubfj same thing applies, use the `html` type selector to set the background to black for the `<html></html>`. I've changed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can wrap the content inside the body tag with a container div element as shown above. 
And I created this [codepen](https://codepen.io/dulara-malindu/pen/pqMVyO) to show how to apply css to achieve your goal.